# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor mayor por el menor y viceversa en una matriz en java?

Tags: java

¡Hola!
Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio que consiste de cambiar de posición el número mayor por el número menor y viceversa en una matriz cuadrada en Java. He alcanzado el punto hasta hallar el número mayor y menor, pero aún no comprendo la lógica de realizar dicho cambio, pensaba en almacenarlo en una variable, para luego cambiar el valor... pero no funciona de esa manera.

A continuación, mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables
    int matriz[][], N;//Se dejará una variable, ya que es una matriz cuadrada
    //Datos a ingresar
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz cuadrada: ");
    N = lectura.nextInt();
    matriz = new int[N][N];
   //Proceso
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para A["+i+"]["+j+"] = ");
            matriz[i][j] = lectura.nextInt();
        }
    }
    ImprimirMatriz("Los datos de la matriz son: ",matriz,N);
    //Variables para hallar el mayor y el menor:
    int mayor, menor;     
    mayor = menor = matriz[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++){
                if(matriz[i][j]>mayor){
                    mayor = matriz[i][j];
                }
                if(matriz[i][j]<menor){
                    menor = matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
    }
    System.out.println("El número mayor es: "+mayor);
    System.out.println("El número menor es: "+menor);
    
    //Cambiar de posición mayor por menor y viceversa
    //¿? Encontrar lógica
}
public static void ImprimirMatriz(String mensaje, int A[][], int N){
    System.out.println("\n"+mensaje+"\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            System.out.print("\t"+A[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera seria ,además de guardar el mayor y el menor numero respectivamente guardes la posición de ambos en la matriz,el `i`and `j` del mayor // el `i` and `j` del menor

```
  int coordenadaMayorx,coordenadaMayory,coordenadaMenorx,coordenadaMenory;

    coordenadaMayorx=coordenadaMayory=coordenadaMenorx=coordenadaMenory=0;
    mayor = menor = matriz[0][0];
  
    for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++){
                if(matriz[i][j]>mayor){
                    mayor = matriz[i][j];
                    coordenadaMayorx=i;
                    coordenadaMayory=j;
                }
                if(matriz[i][j]<menor){
                    menor = matriz[i][j];
                    coordenadaMenorx=i;
                    coordenadaMenory=j;
                }
            }
    }
    System.out.println("El número mayor es: "+mayor);
    System.out.println("El número menor es: "+menor);
//en la posición del mayor guardas el menor
    matriz[coordenadaMayorx][coordenadaMayory]=menor;
//en la posición del menor guardas el mayor
    matriz[coordenadaMenorx][coordenadaMenory]=mayor;

  

     ImprimirMatriz("Los datos de la matriz modificada son: ",matriz,N);
```